# Consume no more than 1 message per hour in Camel?

Tags: java, apache-camel, amazon-sqs

I'm a bit new to camel, so please forgive me if this is a stupid question!

In Camel, I have a list of competing consumers against a queue, `queue-1`. I'd like each consumer to wait 1 hour between attempts to read the queue, but once an hour has passed, each consumer should continuously poll until it receives a message. Once it receives a message, it should process it, and then wait an hour before attempting another read, and so on.

Here's the route I have set up:

```
from("aws-sqs://queue-1?accessKey=ABC&secretKey=XYZ&maxMessagesPerPoll=1")
    .unmarshal().base64()
    .unmarshal().serialization()
    .throttle(1)
    .timePeriodMillis(TimeUnit.HOUR.toMillis(1))
    .bean(new ProcessorBean())
    .marshal().serialization()
    .marshal().base64()
    .to("aws-sqs://queue-2?accessKey=ABC&secretKey=XYZ");
```

It is my understanding that routes execute synchronously (with the exception of [specific components designed to work asynchronously](http://camel.apache.org/asynchronous-routing-engine.html)). Based on that understanding, I believe this route satisfies those requirements.

Will this do what I want? Why or why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your route will consumes a message in the queue and then wait for one hour.

If you want to wait an hour and then read a message, look at ScheduledPollConsumer Options [(Doc)](http://camel.apache.org/polling-consumer.html)
Some options allow to use scheduler like [Quartz2](http://camel.apache.org/quartz2.html) or Spring based scheduler.

Use the [log](http://camel.apache.org/log.html) component if you want to be sure: `.to("log:com.mycompany.order?level=DEBUG")`.

Comment: Excellent. That matches what I'm seeing. Thank you for the confirmation!